# Mutliple Instances of Core Data Stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have created a boiler plate CoreDataStack that I use when developing with iOS.  It is pretty much the same code that apple provides in the appDelegate.  I have a question pertaining to how to pass this around to each view.  From what I have read, the two main options are:

1. Pass the context to each class/ view that needs it.  This seems logical, but it can create a lot of extra code, especially if you need to pass the context to through multiple view that do not need to use it just to get it to the view that does.
2. Reference the appDelegate's context everytime you need it.  Most say this is bad programming, but it can lead to a lot less code than option 1.
3. Why cannot I just create a new stack everytime I need it?  I create a stack in the appDelegate with my CoreDataStack class.  Why cannot I just create it again in another class/ view?  I understand I that I need to make sure it is created in the correct thread, but I am sure I could figure out a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, I just access it through AppDelegate. The CoreData stack is the ONE TIME I use AppDelegate for accessing something, otherwise I avoid it like the plague! If you don't want to do that though, you could use a separate CoreDataStack singleton. Either way, you have everything in one place.

The reason to not recreate the core data stack each time you use it is that each instance of your ManagedObjectContext keeps track of your objects separately. If you create a new one and manipulating objects with it in separate classes, your objects could get out of sync with each other, since each MOC can have it's own internal references to the ManagedObject. Calling `-save` on the MOC does NOT guarantee that the object is immediately written to the datastore, so if you make changes to an object with two different MOCs in two different classes, you could potentially wind up with object conflicts that you will have to merge.

Comment: An explanation for a down vote would be nice so we can see why you think this is not a helpful answer.

Comment: Your answer is valid. Many apps use the AppDelegate. I am also curious to find out why it was down voted. There are many ways to handle accessing CoreData.

Answer (score 0):

I generally remove the AppDelegate Core Data stack and move it into its own class. I use the singleton pattern to manage my core data stack and have a few helper methods in the stack as well. Keep your app delegate as clean as possible. Apple's sample is a quick getting started example.

I have this as a handy function
- (NSManagedObject *)findByEntityName:(NSString *)entityName searchPredicate:(NSPredicate *)searchPredicate;

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can create a new managed object context on demand. To do so you need to create a new context and set it's parent context or persistent store coordinator. However you'll need to be mindful of when you save changes to those contexts and if it is important for other users of the Core Data stack to be able to see unsaved changes. You may also need to handle merge conflicts if multiple contexts might change the same entities.

This is different than recreating the entire Core Data stack on demand and you need at least a shared persistent store coordinator in order to detect and react to such conflicts rather than just allowing them to be resolved arbitrarily by writes to the persistent store.

My personal preference is to use a dependency injection container to supply contexts to controllers. That gives me one location where I can change the default strategy for creating contexts (create a new child of a common parent each time or share one default context) but also allows me to override that strategy on a case by case basis if I want a particular controller to receive a child context (perhaps so all of it's changes can be discarded or if one case needs a different concurrency type).

Comment: Any suggestions on dependency injection containers (frameworks or otherwise)? I was having this same discussion with coworkers earlier today